# PHP online scheduling application

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

For learning purpose, I want to write a simple online scheduling/appointment application with PHP and MySQL. I am not sure how to begin.
These are what the application would allow:
USERS :
- to log in as member and pick a date and time from available time slot
For example, Feb 1, 2014, 8:00AM- 8:30AM
- Submit the date

ADVISORS
- to log in as an admin and set up their schedules (available date and time).

My questions are:
- What tools/frameworks should be used to display Calendar and time?
- What appropriate methods should I store advisors available date and time in MySQL?
Or does anyone knows any similar tutorial as an example that I can follow?

Comment: How about you give me $2000AUD and I will do it for you :)

Comment: That would beat the purpose of learning. Thanks anyway. :-)

Comment: My apologies, I would recommend you to state that this is for learning and someone will share knowledge. As your question sounds like you want the system to be made for you :)))

Comment: No problem. ;-). I will edit to make it clearer. It can be hard to articulate the question. I just want some recommendations from the more experienced so that I can start off in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this is opinionated advice, I would recommend a framework for this learning project. With PHP, you have many good options depending on your preference. For a loose framework, I'd recommend CodeIgniter - good doco and great for those new to frameworks and MVC design. Otherwise, a stricter one would be Zend.

More or less you are going to want CRUD capabilities with your appointments. (Create, Read, Update, and Delete). Here are tutorials for CRUD operations for ZEND and CodeIgniter.

[CodeIgniter CRUD Link](http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/create-crud-codeigniter-tutorial)

[Zend CRUD Link](http://juniorgrossi.com/2011/basic-crud-operations-with-zend-framework/)

After you have read/completed these, you will know what you will need to do to adapt the examples to your specific problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links, James. I will start with Codeigniter since I am a bit familiar with it.